# Questions about JavaCV example

Tags: java, opencv, video, webcam, javacv

HI guys I am experimenting with the use of JavaCV as I want to get to know how it works in order to include it's functionality in a project I have in mind. I have downloaded and set up OpenCV just like what the instructions said and I also have downloaded form bytedeco the JavaCV 1.0 jars that I need to include in my project.

I have started with an example program I found online that basically grabs and save images from a webcam. The code I have written is the following:

```
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.CanvasFrame;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.Frame;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.FrameGrabber;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.VideoInputFrameGrabber;

import org.bytedeco.javacv.*;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.*;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.*;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgproc.*;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgcodecs.*;

public class GrabberShow implements Runnable{

    IplImage image;
    CanvasFrame canvas = new CanvasFrame("Web Cam");

    public GrabberShow(){
        canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void run(){
        FrameGrabber grabber = new VideoInputFrameGrabber(0);
        int i = 0;
        try{
            grabber.start();
            IplImage img;
            while(true){
                img = grabber.grab();
                if(img != null){
                    cvFlip(img, img, 1);
                    cvSaveImage((i++) + "-aa.img", img);
                    canvas.showImage(img);
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        GrabberShow gs = new GrabberShow();
        Thread th = new Thread(gs);
        th.start();
    }
}
```

This is a very straightforward and easy example. The problem I am experiencing can be found on the following lines:

```
img = grabber.grab();
```

and

```
canvas.showImage(img);
```

The problem I face is a Type Mismatch "Cannot convert from Frame to opencv_core.LplImage".

I have tried searching for this online but I was unable to locate a good answer about this. What I did found was the same example only. Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Need to stress out that this the first time I use openCV with Java. I have used it in the past to make and object tracking program but this was  done with native openCV and using Python.

Comment: you should use official [OpenCV Java wrapper](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html), not JavaCV.

Comment: I have read that it's not bad at all to use JavaCV and since this tutorial is using JavaCV I decided to go this way. Why should I use OpenCV instead?

Comment: because it's official, and thus well maintained. Also there are a lot of tutorials, examples, etc... but your choice :D

Answer (score 0):

The code you have looks like it would probably work for javacv version 0.10. For 1.0 the`FrameGrabber`'s return`Frame` objects that then need to be converted to `IplImage` objects using a `OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage`.

```
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.cvFlip;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgcodecs.cvSaveImage;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.CanvasFrame;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.Frame;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.FrameGrabber;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.OpenCVFrameConverter;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.VideoInputFrameGrabber;
```

...

```
public class GrabberShow implements Runnable {

    CanvasFrame canvas = new CanvasFrame("Web Cam");

    public GrabberShow() {
        canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void run() {
        FrameGrabber grabber = new VideoInputFrameGrabber(0);
        OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage converter = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage();

        int i = 0;
        try {
            grabber.start();
            IplImage img;
            while (true) {
                Frame frame = grabber.grab();
                img = converter.convert(frame);
                if (img != null) {
                    cvFlip(img, img, 1);
                    cvSaveImage((i++) + "-aa.img", img);
                    canvas.showImage(frame);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GrabberShow gs = new GrabberShow();
        Thread th = new Thread(gs);
        th.start();
    }
}
```